# java android: how to send data on Bluetooth between android and computer

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, send

I want to create an app that can send data to computer.(data are int)

So, I found some youtube, post, and documents but I couldn't make app that works well.

All documents are so difficult to me  and old that I couldn't understand.

I don't understand from connecting bluetooth to sending data, receiving data between app and computer.

So I hope you to show me codes that sends data successfully.

I want two codes(android app that send data, computer program that receives data).

and I hope you to show all codes(manifest, xml, java code....etc).

Can you write the code for me...?